# How do I check a remote file systems mount permissions?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, filesystems, network-share, mount

I'm mounting a test server to a shared filesystem at work. It's a cifs mount so im looking at this reference page: https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

I want to try and mount in a "know as little as possible" manner to keep people from fudging with the shared filesystem from a test server. So in the docs I see:

> uid=arg
> sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership information. It may be specified as either a username or a numeric uid. When not specified, the default is uid 0. The mount.cifs helper must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the uid in non-numeric form. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY OWNERSHIP AND PERMISSIONS below for more information.

Sounds good. But here's my question:

- How do I check if the server provides ownership information, and if so, how do I found what it actually is?

Bonus question:

- Whats the point of offering permissions when you can just override them to `file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777`?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at CIFS, not NFS. I have never run across a method to extract ownership information from a windows cifs share with linux tools (If anybody knows how - prove me wrong!). This is how it works:

- On the server, the credentials you provide determine your access. You cannot "overrule" a readonly access with `file_mode=0777`, you would get an access denied when trying to write a file in such a case.
- Since a default CIFS share does not export any ownership information, the `uid`, `gid`, `umask`, `file_mode`, `dir_mode` options provide a way to put a linux file security on top of the mounted share. This way, you can say that only a specific local linux user / group is able to read from / write  to your mounted share. If you do not provide these options during mount, default values are used (most likely `uid=0, gid=0, umask=0` for all directories and files inside that share)
- Looking at the official [documentation](http://pserver.samba.org/samba/ftp/cifs-cvs/linux-cifs-client-guide.pdf), it can be read that there are "unix extensions for CIFS" which allows exporting uid / gid ownership information. But I do not know if there is a way to determine whether the server supports these extensions.